# cURL not working in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: php, windows, curl, scheduled-tasks

I've a PHP script that uses cURL to perform certain tasks. At the moment, I have the script running every 10 minutes. This is what I'm running via Windows Task Scheduler.

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe -f C:\wamp\www\autoscripts\index.php

However, for some reason, whenever the argument quoted above is run through the command line, I get the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()". The script works perfectly when I access it via the browser. Is there any reason why PHP isn't able to access the cURL extension via the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Basically, on WampServer, there are TWO php.ini files that you need to be aware of.

- C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini
- C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini

Forgot that the command line uses a different ini file than the web server. :(

Answer (score 3):

Most likely running from command line does not use any ini file that loads the extensions. Open `phpinfo()` from the browser, copy path to loaded ini file and change your task to:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe -c "C:\path\to\php.ini" -f C:\wamp\www\autoscripts\index.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I figured out the issue. See the answer I posted. WampServer has two php.ini files. Command line was using a different ini file from server. :/